# What does the term "background model" mean in statistics?

Tags: modeling, model

I am reading an article in `Systems Biology` where the authors use the term **`background model`** which I guess refers to something related to statistics in general. However, my `Google`search did not result in any significant finding of what the term means!

Here is the context ([Drake et al., 2016](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27499020)):

> The input sets were found to be significantly close (p < 0.012) in a pathway space according to a conservative **background model** generated by 1,000 permutations of the data (Paull et al., 2013), where each input set (kinase regulators, transcriptional regulators, genomic alterations) was swapped with genes of similar network connectivity while the other two were fixed.

Here is another context for the term ([Systems Biology: A Textbook, 2016](https://books.google.fi/books?id=p27kCwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Systems%20Biology:%20A%20Textbook&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq8I_IqtfOAhVJEpoKHdx1CnUQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=Systems%20Biology%3A%20A%20Textbook&f=false)) which I found by searching. However, still I cannot wrap my mind around this notion:

> To test if a pattern is significantly abundant in a network, the network is compared with a random graph that serves as **background model**.

It would be great to define this notion in plain English and/or with a help of an example.

Comment: This seems like a synonym for the statistical term "null model": a framework using probability theory to show what type of data we would expect to see if the effect/signal we are interested in were absent. This is a way to get a handle on false positives: we should use techniques that only seldom claim to make discoveries on the null model.

Comment: @eric_kernfeld: It makes sense! Now that I search these two terms together, I get more hits. Thanks!
For instance I found this: "To detect motif sites on
a sequence with a given `PWM`, a **null model**, usually called the **background model**, is first estimated from all the bases of the sequence; then a sequential scan is applied to calculate the probability ratio of every word of width `w` under the `PWM` model over the background model." (Chen and Zhou, 2009)

Comment: OK; posting as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Background model" is used here as a synonym for the statistical term "null model". These terms mean a framework using probability theory to show what type of data we would expect to see if the effect/signal we are interested in were absent. This is a way to get a handle on false positives: we should use techniques that only seldom claim to make discoveries under the null (background) model.